# Can WIFI Direct and 3G Data Session Concurrently Work?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi-direct

Can 3G Data Session and WIFI Direct concurrently work?? if so, then two IPaddress Exist, will it cause confusion?  one example:

A use 3G  to download a video file, now the progress is 50%. Now A select a picture, and want to use WIFIDirect to share to B. will this succeed without interrupt the video file downloading?? say the WIFI connection is ok, then A have 2 Ip address, in Picture sharing , which Ip Address will be used?

Answer (score 2):

I am running my own WiFi Direct application on my Galaxy Nexus while my 3G is on and I have not experienced any problems so far. This is most certainly because WiFi Direct application is using android.net.wifi.p2p package. When you get your IP over 3G, android.net.wifi package is used. Therefore, there can be two different IP addresses availabe for your device. And for picture sharing, local IP will be used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think two simultaneous connections are possible because when you turn-on WiFi, it automatically turns off 3g and uses WiFi as default connection. And its vice versa.

At least this is the behavior i've noticed on all of my android phones.

Comment: I haven't experience with Wifi-Direct yet, but the logical think is that the route table for wifi direct would be totally diferent as working with a WLAN. The think is you can have both connections ready at the same time while you don't connect to a WLAN so when you connect it 3G is disabled as WIFI is the most prioritary interface. However wifidirect is not made for connecting to the network but to connect two different devices and share thinks. That should only make an entry in the route table to send packets only to that ip address through WIFI-DIRECT so network connection will be available

Answer (score 0):

Can 3G Data Session and WIFI Direct concurrently work??
yes... can work

will this succeed without interrupt the video file downloading??
yes..

In Picture sharing , which Ip Address will be used?
Local IP i guess. havent checked though

Comment: For Picture sharing app, when it use socket, the 2 IP address available, and say it did not explicityly bind any ip address, then which ip address be used is confused!!

Answer (score 0):

You can route using requestRouteToHost API i.e. Video Download can happening as below if you know the host address where the Video is stored:

```
    ConnectivityManager connManager = null;

    if(mContext != null) {
        connManager = (ConnectivityManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo[] netInfos = connManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for(int loop_index=0;loop_index<netInfos.length;loop_index++){          
            switch(netInfos[loop_index].getType())
            {
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI:
                if(netInfos[loop_index].getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED){
                    connectionSet = connManager.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI, lookupHost("Video Stored Address"));
                }
                break;

            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
                if(netInfos[loop_index].getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)

                break;

            default:
                if(netInfos[loop_index].getState()== NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)

                break;
            }
        }
    }

private static int lookupHost(String hostname) {
    InetAddress inetAddress;
    try {
        inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        return -1;
    }
    byte[] addrBytes;
    int addr;
    addrBytes = inetAddress.getAddress();
    addr = ((addrBytes[3] & 0xff) << 24)
            | ((addrBytes[2] & 0xff) << 16)
            | ((addrBytes[1] & 0xff) << 8)
            |  (addrBytes[0] & 0xff);
    return addr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the Android phones do not allow concurrent use of two interfaces at the same time, it can be done through application development. I have developed a download accelerator for Windows that uses both WIFI and Ethernet interfaces for TCP connections at the same time.

The two interfaces can be used for TCP connections only, having two different IP addresses. You can develop an application for Android phones that will first determine the size of a file in bytes and send a bytes request on each interface. Remember that UDP connections are impossible in concurrent interfaces.

Comment: Some coding samples would be appropriate.